# DAQ Matlab toolbox: how to count trigger events without an edge counter channel and how to output different value at each successive trigger

Tags: matlab, nidaqmx

I need your help with the session based interface for the Matlab DAQ toolbox. I have not been able to find much help in the MathWorks tutorials or examples. I am currently using a USB-6003 DAQ from NI.

So basically in my system I have 2 analog output channels (ch1 and ch2) and 1 analog input channel (ch3), and what I am trying to do is to drive the output voltage in ch1 from 0V to 10V in steps of 1V, with ch2 constant and then repeat the loop in ch1 for a different voltage in ch2.  As for the analog input ch3, I am triggering it some time after triggering the ch1. My triggers are being externally generated by a function generator.

What I have been struggling with is:

1) How to at each successive trigger event output a different value in the ch1.

2) And how after 11 triggers, can I change ch2 output's.

3) How to save the input in a different location between trigger events, so it does not get overwritten by the next event.

My main constraints are:

1) I cannot use an edge-counter channel to count the triggers because I only have two PFI channels and I need both, one to trigger ch1 and the other ch3 (I cannot use only one).

2) I cannot use wait or any other software time function, because I need a high speed acquisition system (it is for a laser microscope)

3) I need two have at least 2 sessions running in parallel because my DAQ does not allow simultaneous tasks in the same session.

I have attached a channel's time diagram of what I am trying to do.
[Channels diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM6M4.png)

Answer (score 0):

## Caution

*"I need a high speed acquisition system"*

USB might not be the right option. Using USB as the control/data transport mechanism is slow compared to other computer I/O, like PCIe or [EtherCAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherCAT). If, after you get this working, you determine that you need lower latency and jitter, my recommendation is to try [CompactRIO](http://www.ni.com/compactrio/whatis/) and [LabVIEW Real-Time](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3938/en/).

Compounding the performance is the on-demand nature of the USB-6003. While both analong input and analog output are controlled by electrical signals (the start trigger and sample clock) and have their data automatically transferred by the driver, the digital input and counter are only software-timed, which means that reading data isn't automatic and must be prompted by you, the user, with a read command.

Since the only way you can get digital data from a USB-6003 is on-demand, your only option is to wait for it; there is no way to be notified that a new edge has arrived. Other devices (like the PCIe-63xx X Series or cDAQ-940x devices) support [digital input change detection](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4102/en/), which causes a [software event](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/5384/en/) to be sent to the program. If you had one of these devices, then you wouldn't have to wait.

## Suggestion

However, if you change your triggering and data strategies a little, I still think you can achieve the kind of I/O you want. You'll then be able to evaluate its speed and reliability to decide if you need to upgrade DAQ hardware.

### New triggering and data strategy

[image]

The core idea is: instead of keeping the channels on their own "time base", unify them to a single time base and use that to coordinate the voltage updates. By doubling the frequency of your external trigger, all three channels can share the same timing. In other words, both the analog input task and the analog output task use the same external signal as their sample clock.

1. Double the frequency of the FGEN's trigger signal.
2. Repeat an analog output sample if the level doesn't need to change.
3. Throw an analog input sample away if it coincides with an output level change.

The analog output samples would be:

```
ch1  ch2

0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0
1.0  0.0
1.0  0.0
2.0  0.0
2.0  0.0
0.0  1.0
0.0  1.0
```

### New program strategy

Now that both the analog input and analog output are using the FGEN as their sample clock, the MATLAB routine only needs to prepare the operation and then monitor/feed it. The hardware will be able to generate and acquire without any intervention from the PC, but the PC will need to periodically read analog input data and write more analog output data to keep the driver satisfied.

I don't know how much of the DAQmx API MATLAB exposes, but you can ask the driver how many samples are left in the device's buffer

- Analog input is `DAQmxGetReadAvailSampPerChan` ([doc](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370471AE-01/mxcprop/attr1223/))
- Analog output is `DAQmxGetWriteSpaceAvail` ([doc](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370471AE-01/mxcprop/attr1460/))

### Reference

**NI USB-6003 Specifications**
http://digital.ni.com/manuals.nsf/websearch/666A752FCC177B0186257CD8006C24C8

Comment: Thank you @Joe , your suggestion of doubling the FGEN frequency is really helpful and smart. I had not though about that... 
So even implementing that alteration, I still need to change ch1 every 2 triggers. 
Do you have an idea on how to implement that in Matlab (session based) so that the output array is like the one you suggested for ch1? I only know how to output an entire array after a trigger event.

Comment: I haven't used MATLAB in 15 years, so I'm not very familiar with it. However, it looks like you want to use `queueOutputData` in combination with the session's `ScansQueueds.Rate` value. See www.mathworks.com/help/daq/generate-analog-output-signals.html for more. I added another paragraph to highlight the fire-forget-and-monitor nature of this approach.